# Varying a popup menu background color (programmatically)

Tags: java, android

Is there an any way to change popup menu background color programmatically?
I know it can do by style.xml but in my app, background color should be change according to a variable (not constant color).
Is there any idea?

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ViewProfileActivity.this, viewProfileSettings);
            popup.getMenu().add(userAccountSettings.getDisplay_name() + " more...");
            popup.getMenu().add("Ban user");
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
```

I know there is an option like that

```
 <style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/darkergray</item>
</style>
```

But i need to do that programmatically to make color variable

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: there it is. nothing new on there